# Can we avoid the repetition of String enum value?

Tags: typescript

I'm using this code:

```
type Group = {
  [key in ROLES]?: string;
};

enum ROLES {
  simple = "simple",
  admin = "admin",
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the "repetition" of `simple = "simple"`/`admin = "admin"`?

Can we have simply:

```
enum ROLES {
  simple,
  admin,
}
```

Comment: if using an enum is not required, you could just define those keys as a type:
`type Roles = "simple" | "admin"`. and then call `key in Roles` like you do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `enum` you declared is valid TypeScript. But instead of strings, this `enum` contains numbers and is equivalent to:

```
enum ROLES {
  simple = 0,
  admin = 1,
}
```

But you can still extract the key names from `ROLES` to build the `Group` type.

```
type Group = {
  [key in `${keyof typeof ROLES}`]?: string;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=3&pln=6&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBASg8gGQKIGUoG8BQUoGcCWEADgDbAA02UAhgCYT4iUC+mmALgJ5HBQDiAJwD2YIlAC8GKgG0A1sE5RGUAAYASdPM5CAZlC49dsRKmYqAugH4AXHnYDGAcwDcmZs6A)